# why is $header undefined here?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

i am trying to send mail using php. i have removed the comment from the SMTP port and mail but Apache throws undefined variable $header in line no.5. what is wrong here?

```
<?php include "head.php";?>
<?php
$from= "smechailes@gmail.com";
$Headers = "";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; Charset= iso-859-1 \r\n";
$header .= "From: ".$from." \r\n";
$to = "setok321@gmail.com";
$subject = "test-mail";
$message ="<h1>hello</h1>";
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
echo (int)$mail;
?>
<?php include "foot.php";?>
```

Comment: you have declared $Headers = ""; but using $headers

Comment: it's actually $header so it doesn't match regardless of case sensitivity.

Comment: make $Headers to $headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$Headers = "";` by `$header = "";`

**Explanation:**

PHP variables are case sensitive.

You have initialised variable `$Headers` and assuming it to be `$header`.

And concatenating to `$header`, which is undefined.

Either change `$Headers` to `$header`

OR

change

`$header` to `$Headers` at all places.

Comment: you should have post it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

You are using the concatenating assignment operator when you use `.=`:

```
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
```

is equivalent to:

```
$header = $header . "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
```

Meaning $header is used as a part of the assignment and should exist prior.

Answer (score 0):

use below code, because on line 5 $header is not defined you are concatenate the string

```
<?php include "head.php";?>
<?php
$from= "smechailes@gmail.com";
//$Headers = "";
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; Charset= iso-859-1 \r\n";
$header .= "From: ".$from." \r\n";
$to = "setok321@gmail.com";
$subject = "test-mail";
$message ="<h1>hello</h1>";
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
echo (int)$mail;
?>
<?php include "foot.php";?>
```